# How to redirect domain to root domain, but with subdomain homepage going somewhere else?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

Trying to redirect a subdomain to a root domain on an Apache server via .htaccess, but need the subdomain homepage to be redirected elsewhere. For example:

```
blog.example.com --> example.com/blog/
blog.example.com/post-title --> example.com/post-title
```

Currently I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$    http://example.com/blog/    [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which I feel should work, but I'm getting a "too many redirects" error.

To make things even more awkward, there's a few stray pages I need to manually redirect to new locations, for example:

```
blog.example.com/incorrect-category-name-1 --> example.com/correct-category-name-1
blog.example.com/incorrect-category-name-2 --> example.com/correct-category-name-2
```

Is all this possible within 1 .htaccess file?

Comment: Where does `blog.example.com` point to? The same place as `example.com`? Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: @w3d blog.example.com points to the old blog currently, but needs to point to example.com/blog/. Example.com is the new site homepage, not the blog.
.htaccess is in the blog.example.com subdomain.

Comment: But I assume `blog.example.com` and `example.com` are on the same filesystem otherwise you wouldn't be getting a "too many redirects" error?

Comment: @w3d Yes they are on the same filesystem - just not sure how to structure the redirect in that case!

Comment: You are still missing a bit of important information... _where_ on the filesystem does `blog.example.com` point to? For instance, does `blog.example.com` actually point to `example.com/blog`? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the `.htaccess` file in the root of `blog.example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the HTTP_HOST is not blog.example.com then finish
# - Avoid a redirect loop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=blog.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Specific redirects...
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/blog/ [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^incorrect-category-name-1$ http://example.com/correct-category-name-1 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^incorrect-category-name-2$ http://example.com/correct-category-name-2 [R=302,L]

# Catch all redirect
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change the 302 (temporary) redirects to 301 (permanent) when you are happy it's working OK. Permanent redirects are catched by the browser so can make testing tricky. Make sure you have cleared your browser cache first.